# Yandexmapkit api android отрисовка баллуна

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api

Приветствую. Возникла необходимость интегрировать апи карт в приложение. Выбор пал на яндекс и я взялся за освоение. Но тут же возникла и проблема. Результат нужен такой - при нажатии на карту вылезает баллун с адресом тапа. При нажатии на баллун адрес передается дальше (выбор адреса доставки для интернет магазина). Сделал кастомный Overlay, добавляю баллун по тапу и тут вот она - проблема. Иногда он добавляется сразу, а иногда только после взаимодействия с мапконтроллером (перемещение карты, увеличение зума итп). Не сталкивались с такой проблемой? Как можно решить?

Код ниже

```
public class YandexMapActivity extends Activity {

    OverlayManager mOverlayManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yandex_map);
        Decorator.setStatusBarColor(this);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        mOverlayManager = mapView.getMapController().getOverlayManager();

        mOverlayManager.getMyLocation().setEnabled(false);

        OverlayGeoCode overlayGeoCode = new OverlayGeoCode(mapView.getMapController());
        overlayGeoCode.setContext(this);
        mapView.getMapController().getOverlayManager().addOverlay(overlayGeoCode);
    }
}
```

Кастомный Overlay

```
public class OverlayGeoCode extends Overlay implements GeoCodeListener {

    Context context;
    Resources res;

    public OverlayGeoCode(MapController mapController) {
        super(mapController);
        res = App.context.getResources();
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(float x, float y) {
        getMapController().getDownloader().getGeoCode(this, getMapController().getGeoPoint(new ScreenPoint(x, y)));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFinishGeoCode(final GeoCode geoCode) {
        clearOverlayItems();
        if (geoCode != null){
            Log.i("geo_code", geoCode.getDisplayName());
//            getMapController().getMapView().post(new Runnable() {
//                @Override
//                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            // Create an object for the layer
            OverlayItem tapOverlay = new OverlayItem(geoCode.getGeoPoint(), getLavkaStyleTextDrawable(geoCode.getDisplayName()));
            // Create a balloon model for the object
            BalloonItem tapBalloon = new BalloonItem(context, tapOverlay.getGeoPoint());
            tapBalloon.setText(geoCode.getDisplayName());
            tapBalloon.setOnBalloonListener(new OnBalloonListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBalloonViewClick(BalloonItem balloonItem, View view) {
                    Log.i("click", "on balloon");
                }

                @Override
                public void onBalloonShow(BalloonItem balloonItem) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBalloonHide(BalloonItem balloonItem) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBalloonAnimationStart(BalloonItem balloonItem) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBalloonAnimationEnd(BalloonItem balloonItem) {

                }
            });
            // Add the balloon model to the object
            tapOverlay.setBalloonItem(tapBalloon);
            tapOverlay.setVisible(true);
            // Add the object to the layer
            clearOverlayItems();
            addOverlayItem(tapOverlay);
//                }
//            });
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object another) {
        return 0;
    }

    private BitmapDrawable getLavkaStyleTextDrawable(String text) {
        int padding_pixels = Decorator.dipToPx(8);
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("click", "on text click");
            }
        });
        textView.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.balloon_drawable));
        textView.setTextColor(Decorator.BLACK);
        textView.setPadding(padding_pixels, padding_pixels, padding_pixels, padding_pixels);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = null;
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());

            textView.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bm = textView.getDrawingCache();
            if (bm != null) {
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, bm);
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Все закомментиованые строки, логи и прочее - различные эксперименты. Пытался обрабатывать добавление баллуна как в отдельном потоке, так и в UI, результат один. Яндекс поддержки пока нет, пишут, что разрабатывают новый апи, а со старым делайте что хотите :(

Answer (score 1):

Для этого я использую в классе Overlay вызов метода notifyRepaint класса MapController:

```
getMapController().notifyRepaint();
```

Он дает команду карте перерисовать слои. Естественно, перерисовка также делается автоматически при обработки специальных событий (зума, сдвига и др.).

В вашем случае:

```
//добавить точку на карту
addOverlayItem(tapOverlay);
//перерисовать карту для мгновенного отображения указанной точки
getMapController().notifyRepaint();
```